# Why doesn't F() macro (to store string in .text) compile?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

At the bottom of the [documentation on PROGMEM](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM#sourceblock8), it shows what looks like a wonderfully simple way to compile strings into the program .text segment:

> ## The F() macro
>
> When an instruction like:

```
Serial.print("Write something");
```

> is used, the string to be printed is normally saved in RAM. If your sketch prints a lot of stuff on the Serial Monitor, you can easily fill the RAM. If you have free FLASH memory space, you can easily indicate that the string must be saved in FLASH using the syntax:

```
Serial.print(F("Write something that is stored in FLASH"));
```

However, I have had only bad luck getting this to compile.

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
static const struct {short cmd; const char *txt;} cmds[] = {
    {2, F("Hi")},
};
```

It complains with

```error
t.c:3:  error: initializer element is not constant
{2, F("hi")},
^
t.c:3: error: (near initialization for 'cmds[0].txt')
exit status 1
initializer element is not constant
```

Without the `F` macro, it compiles just fine.

```
    {2, "Hi"},
```

Does anyone have experience getting this to work?  I have like 10K of strings I'd like to get into the program space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **F** macro can only be used in executable parts of the code, not variable definitions.  And because struct member can't have the PROGMEM attribute, you have to do it in two steps: declare each text string in PROGMEM, then use the PROGMEM address in the struct.

An array of structs can be in PROGMEM, too.

```
static const char cmd_0_txt[] PROGMEM = "Hello";
static const char cmd_1_txt[] PROGMEM = "World";

struct cmd_t {short cmd; const char *txt; }; // the struct type

// An array of structs in PROGMEM
static const cmd_t cmds[] PROGMEM = {
    {2, cmd_0_txt},
    {2, cmd_1_txt},
};

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin( 9600 );
  Serial.println( F("Test") );

  for (uint8_t i=0; i < sizeof(cmds)/sizeof(cmds[0]); i++) {

    // First, read the PROGMEM txt member (a pointer to the text)
    const char *ptr = (const char *) pgm_read_word( &cmds[i].txt );  // cast required

    // Next, read each text character from that PROGMEM location
    for (;;) {
      char c = pgm_read_byte( ptr++ );
      if (!c)
        break;
      Serial.print( c );
    }
    Serial.println();
  }
}

void loop()
{}
```

Comment: I guess I expected too much from the macro.  That was to put the string in program memory and put the pointer to it in data.  Given the size of the command table, I am thinking I might have to do some dodgy "include it twice" with different macro definitions to achieve the desired result.  Thanks for one way forward.

Comment: But aren't you using it in a variable definition area?  What is the critical difference between what you have and what I have?

Comment: This is not a variable definition: `Serial.println( F("Test") );`  That's the only place the F macro is used in my example.  The PROGMEM attribute can be used in several places, but the F macro is restricted to executable lines of code.